# Inconsistent results when testing a chan processing function

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, core.async, midje

The `process-async` function tested within the `midje` framework produces inconsistent results. Most of the time it checks as expected, but from time to time, it reads `out.json` at its initial state (`""`). I rely on the `async-blocker` function to wait on `process-async` before checking.

What's wrong with my approach?

```
(require '[[test-with-files.core :refer [with-files public-dir]])

(defn async-blocker [fun & args]
  (let [chan-test (chan)]
    (go (>! chan-test (apply fun args)))
    (<!! chan-test)))

(defn process-async
  [channel func]
  (go-loop  []
    (when-let  [response  (<! channel)]
      (func response)
      (recur))))

(with-files [["/out.json" ""]]
    (facts "About `process-async"
           (let [channel (chan)
                 file (io/resource (str public-dir "/out.json"))
                 write #(spit file (str % "\n") :append true)]
             (doseq [m ["m1" "m2"]] (>!! channel m))
             (async-blocker process-async channel write)
             (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp file)) => (just ["m1" "m2"] :in-any-order)
             )
           )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `process-async` returns immediately with *"[...] a channel which will receive the result of the body when
completed"* (since `go-loop` is just syntactic sugar for `(go (loop ...))` and `go` returns immediately).

This means that the blocking `<!!` in `async-blocker` will have a value almost immediately and the order in which the `go` blocks from `process-async` and `async-blocker` get executed is undetermined. It might be that most of the time the block from `process-async` executes first because it gets created first, but that is not much of a guarantee in a concurrent context.

According to the documentation for `<!!` it *"Will return nil if closed. Will block if nothing is available."* This means that if you can assume that the return value of `(apply fun args)` is a channel returned by `go`, you should be able to block by using `<!!` in the following way:

```
(defn async-blocker [fun & args]
  (<!! (apply fun args)))
```

This will unblock  once there is a value in the channel (i.e. the return value from the `go` block).

There are other options to wait for the result of another `go` block. You could for example provide the original `chan-test` as an argument to `fun` and then `put` a value in `chan-test` when the `go` block created in `fun` terminates. But I think, given the code you showed, other approaches might be unnecessarily more complicated.